# How to get variable value from aspx file's Javascript event handler to aspx.cs file event handler

Tags: c#, asp.net, event-handling

### Current Situation:

- Here is a page where phone number asked as an input with area code as users wish to select from a dropdown like below,

[image]

- Whenever '***Send Request***' button hit, an onClick event handler via JQuery (see below) fired, and input value changed to a number including area code on frontend,

[image]

Here is related **foo.aspx**;

```
<asp:TextBox ID="ClientPhone" runat="server" CssClass="form-control" type="tel" Visible="false"></asp:TextBox>

<div class="saveButtonLocation">
    <asp:Button ID="Submit" ValidationGroup="AddWebsiteWizard" runat="server" Text="Send Request" CssClass="btn btn-success" OnClick="Submit_Click" OnClientClick="this.disabled=true; this.value='Sending Request'" UseSubmitBehavior="false"/>
</div>

<script type="text/javascript">
    function pageLoad() {
        setupInput();
    }

    function setupInput() {

        var input = $("#<%=ClientPhone.ClientID %>")[0];

        if (input) {
            var iti = window.intlTelInput(input, {
                utilsScript: "../../node_modules/intl-tel-input/build/js/utils.js"
            });

            $("#<%=Submit.ClientID %>").on('click', function (e) {
                if (input.value.trim()) {
                    if (iti.isValidNumber()) {
                        var number = iti.getNumber(intlTelInputUtils.numberFormat.E164);
                        console.log(input);
                        input.value = number;
                    }
                }
            });
        }
    }
</script>
```

And here is what I got when I highlight `**ClientPhone**` and it's `Text` value on **foo.aspx.cs**;

[image]

### Expected Result:

I want to get phone number within **foo.aspx.cs** including area code as well.

### Notes:

- As a frontend dev, I'd love to hear possible ways and alternatives to handle this frontend manipulated data on backend as well,
- And as per the code above, there's `onClick` method belong to submit button a.k.a `Send Request`, not for an input field which is **`ClientPhone`** itself, since users should be able to play with it as many times as they wish until it's been submitted.

Answer (score 2):

Well, code behind can't touch, know, see ANYTHING until you post the page back to the web server.

The web server is JUST sitting there, and any one of 20 people can "post back" the web page. Until that occurs, you MUST assume that the code behind does not exist (the page class (the code behind) does not exist yet). And thus the page life cycle has not started.

Remember, the web server is ONE computer, not a desktop computer for each person. So the web server will start a "processing" of the ONE page submitted to the web server.

So, you have this:

[image]

The page is JUST sitting on the users' desktop. There is NOT a web page on the server - none! Once IIS sends that page to the client browser?

Then on the server side, the page is dumped. And the code behind (page class objects) is disposed, tossed out of memory.

At this point, the user can close their laptop lid, or click on their favorites to browse to a different site. Your web server does not care and DOES NOT even know that the user moved on, closed their browser or even turned off their computer.

So, if you want to see the value of a text box in code behind?

Then you need to post the page. In most cases, a plain Jane asp.net button will do the job.

When you click that button - a so called standard server control, THEN the page life cycle starts.

This occurs:

[image]

And once the page hits the server?

Then IIS and .net will load the page, create the page class, initialize the code behind, and THEN start running the code behind. Note how your code behind can ONLY change the browser page, and during this time, the user sees NOTHING. this is why say if you do a for (i=1;i<= 10;i++) loop to update a text box value, the user will ALWAYS see just the final "10" value.

In effect code behind changes are NEVER seen by the user UNTIL the whole page life cycle is done.

So, you now have this:

[image]

Note VERY close, for the purpose of teaching, I did NOT show the browser is sitting on the users desktop (they of course see that spinner/wait of the browser).

Only AFTER ALL of the code behind has 100% completed, then and ONLY then does now the whole page travel back to the client side.

For example, this:

[image]

Note again, how I do NOT show/have in the above diagram a web page sitting on the server. Once the page is sent back to client side, then on server side?

The page is dumped, the page class (and variables you have in code) are 100% dumped and disposed of.

Now, the web server is just waiting for you or any one to press a button or some such to start this so called "page lifecycle" over again.

So, to get that simple text box value back to the server side? (along with any other controls, and text boxes, and drop downs and whatever you have?

You have to have a another post-back and the whole page life cycle starts over again.

And keep in mind that when that WHOLE NEW page travels back down to the browser side?

It is re-loaded, re-plotted, and even the client side JavaScript code is re-loaded, re-initialized and starts over again from scratch.

This every time starting from scratch? It is what we call "state-less".

This means for the most part, if you trigger a "round trip" or so called page life cycle, then you have to assume that everything starts over from scratch each time. This also means then that some simple code and variables you have in "code behind" will also NOT retain their values. They ONLY exist DURING the short time the page is up on the server being processed.

So, often the goal and "buzz" today?

Well, a lot of tools exist that let you write (or at least attempt to) write MORE code to run in the browser. This gives "instant" response (much like a desktop program). It responds well, since we not even talking or using the server side code or system at all! (no round trip occurs - and they are not only slower, but expensive in terms of server load).

But of course the down side is you don't have use of that wonderful and easy, and reliable server side code. And that server side code can do a lot of things like fill out a gridview, maybe a combo box (dropdown list) or whatever from a database.

Client side code (JavaScript) does not have use of those server resources, or even the code behind. However, since as I noted, people "try" to move more code to the browser. So, you can adopt what is called a web method, or "ajax" call. what that does is call some server side code, but does NOT incur a whole page post-back, and round trip.

So, say we drop in a text box, a label, and a button.

We want the button click to take the text from the text box, convert to upper case, and then shove the results into the label.

This would be 100% server side code, and thus use the above page life cycle.

So, we drag + drop in the above 3 controls.

We have this:

```
            Enter some text :<asp:TextBox ID="TextBox1" runat="server" Width="400px"></asp:TextBox>
            <br />
            <br />
            <asp:Button ID="cmdServerSide" runat="server" Text="Server side code - run" />
            <br />
            <br />
            <asp:Label ID="Label1" runat="server" Text="Result:"></asp:Label>
```

In the designer view, we can double click on the button, and we will be instant jumped to the code behind.

```
    protected void cmdServerSide_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        string MyText = TextBox1.Text;
        MyText = MyText.ToUpper();

        Label1.Text = "Result = " + MyText;

    }
```

So the result when run is now this:

[image]

OK, what about doing this 100% client side? Without server side code?

Well, let's drop in another plain Jane button, but now write 100% client side code.

In fact, let's SPLIT the tasks. We will take the text box, confirm that the user entered at least 8 or more characters, convert to upper case, BUT THEN call server side code to set the label.

So, let's drop in another button, and we now have this code:

```
            <asp:Button ID="cmdSomeClientAndServer" runat="server" Text="client and server side Button"
                OnClick="cmdSomeClientAndServer_Click"
                OnClientClick="return myuppercheck()"                    
                />

            <script>
                function myuppercheck() {

                tBox = document.getElementById('<%= TextBox1.ClientID %>')
                strText = tBox.value
                    if (strText.length <= 5) {
                        alert("You must enter more then 5 characters")
                        return false
                    }
                    // ok, more then 5 chars, conver to upper case
                    // and put value BACK into text box
                    strText = strText.toUpperCase()
                    tBox.value = strText
                    return true   // let server side button code run
                }
            </script>
```

So, now that button runs BOTH the client side code, and THEN runs the server side code. However, rather nice is that if the client side JS function does not return true, then the server side code does not run.

So, client side:

We check if the user entered more then 5 characters.

Then we convert the text to upper case, shove back into text box, and then return TRUE. Returning true will then allow the server side code we attached to the SAME button to run.

the server side code is thus this:

```
    protected void cmdSomeClientAndServer_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        // take the text box, and shove into the label

        Label1.Text = "Result = " + TextBox1.Text;
    }
```

So, now we have this effect when run:

[image]

so the issue then tends to be?

Well, do I really need the server side code to run. and if we want to use text box and values server side then we have to allow/have that post-back.

Of course, we could call server side code, and NOT use a post-back (and that big round trip), but call a web method, or so called use "ajax".

But, let's leave that for another post.

So, from above, the way we pass the text box to code behind?

Well, we kind of really don't do that, but post the WHOLE page back, and then code behind is free to see any control on the web page, and we are free in that server side code to change any control we want, and once that code runs then that WHOLE page is re-sent back to client side, and the client side will re-load its code. (and on server side, the code behind and web page is tossed out, disposed. Server is now ready to accept a post back from you, or any other user).

Comment: Thank you so much for very detailed answer but, I still couldn't succeed on achieving the goal of getting same data apart from understanding how it should be working theoretically. I'll accept it anyway but is it possible for you to display ready-to-use solution for the presented code within the question above?

Comment: Sure, but keep in mind that "all of the code" and markup was provided here. I can of course zip the solution, and let you play with it. Busy day, but later this evening I'll post the working project above. You really don't need anything more then to just create/add a new web page to your project, and then paste in the sample markup and code. So, there not really any more code or anything then what markup and code I posted here. I do believe "more" valuable here is that grasp of the page life cycle. Without that grasp, then how things work with code behind vs client side is vudu.

Comment: I think you misinterpreted my comment above. I was asking about how to implement this logic to the code above in my question if possible.

Comment: the concepts contained in this post gives the road map here. It not clear what that js routine does, and without that knowledge, I have to guess about that js code. It not clear if the js code library only allows numbers, or whatever it does? But, yes, you can have the client side js code run, and not post-back or call server side code. or the button can do both. So, it not clear "where" the area code number is saved, or contained, or to be pulled from.